# Write alternative query in MSSQL view

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a view which selects records from table1 if table1 does not contain so it goes to next alternative table like table2 or table3 etc.

Pl advice.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is to find the first match and return the results...then a view is not going to help you here. You need a stored procedure instead...something like...

```
create procedure spname
as
begin
    if exists (select * from table1 [where clause condition])
      select * from table1
    else if exists (select * from table2 [where clause condition])
      select * from table2
    else if exists (select * from table3 [where clause condition])
      select * from table3
end
```

Comment: Can i put any condition like:

Comment: if (timestampt < getdate() -30)
select * from table1;
else
select * from table2;

can you please advice how to put into view?

Comment: yes, you can put whatever condition you want...and no, as explained you can't put that into a view